# tkinter, print text when hovering over OptionMenu objects

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, optionmenu, tkinter-menu

So I got to change the colors as well as change colors while hovering over menu objects created using the OptionMenu in tkinter.

I even have text printing when I hover over the button, but the second I drop down the menu, it won't print anymore.

What am I doing wrong? How can I print when you click to open the OptionMenu and and move around through the selections?

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
OZoneIzotopeSemiWhite = "#c0c4ca"
buttonBackground = "#303336"
buttonforeground = "#cdd0d7"
BACKGROUND2 = "#1e1f21"

class DropDownButton():
    def __init__(self, parent, placement, opTions, **kw):
        self.parent = parent
        self.options = opTions

        self.om_variable = tk.StringVar(self.parent)
        self.om_variable.set(self.options[0])
        self.om_variable.trace('w', self.option_select)

        self.om = tk.OptionMenu(self.parent, self.om_variable, *self.options)
        self.om["menu"].config(fg=buttonforeground, bg=buttonBackground, activebackground=OZoneIzotopeSemiWhite, activeforeground=BACKGROUND2, borderwidth = 0)
        self.om.config(fg=buttonforeground, bg=buttonBackground, activebackground=OZoneIzotopeSemiWhite, activeforeground=BACKGROUND2, bd =0)
        self.om.place(x = placement, y = 2)
        self.om.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.om.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        if self.om == self.options[0]:
            print ("Hello")
        elif self.om_variable.get() == self.options[1]:
            print ("Hello 2!")
        else:
            print("Hell0 3!")

    def on_leave(self, enter):
        print ("leave")

    def option_select(self, *args):
        print (self.om_variable.get())

root = tk.Tk()
DropDownButton(root, 55, ['one', 'two', 'three'])
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong as such, but you might need to alter what you do or your expectations. When a menu is popped up by clicking on a menubutton widget — as created by the option menu code — the mouse pointer is *grabbed* by the menu that has popped up, and this state continues until you do an action that selects something (or you click or release outside the menu, which cancels). Your styling, which depends on the state of the menubutton, might be noticing this and going into something slightly unexpected to you.

By the way, if you pop up the menu using key bindings, the differing look is actually useful as the focus will also be on the actual popup menu.